# Detecting use of iOS's "Hide my Email" on website signup

Tags: ios, iphone, web, email-validation

Apple's latest changes which allow users to hide their IP, hide their email, etc. are creating problems for my web-based app (non-native) which relies upon these things to build a sense of *who* a person is.

In most situations, I can see why these are great "features" to have, however in my use case I have a voting platform that utilizes things like email address and IP to do a decent job at detecting duplicate votes or fraudulent vote (i.e, logins from other countries, etc.).

*Now, before anyone says "These aren't foolproof ways of identifying a person" and derail my actual question: I know. I'm not looking for perfection, but these methodologies shed light on the 95%+ of people who might be trying to circumvent our voting system.*

Apple placing the ability to circumvent these measures by being right up in front of the user as a first-class feature shoots major holes in my existing strategy.

Is there a way to detect if a user is utilizing these methods to where I could prompt them that they need to sign-up without using these features?

I think it would be easily justifiable to explain that, due to the nature of the application being a voting website, the ability to create multiple aliases would directly undermine the purpose of the site.

Perhaps there is an email address pattern to look for (I know in my test cases, I was getting email addresses @icloud.com).

If there is no reasonable way, I need to rethink the entire process of identifying individuals and preventing aliases (phone / text confirmation, etc).

Comment: Ip is not good as it change regularly. You could create a UIID, the first time user launch the app and store it in a safe place on user iCloud  so each time a user want to vote this is will enable to verify he has  not already voted. This will be available through all his devices..

Comment: Why not store the vendorIdentifier along with the account? Then later if they sign up with a new email address, you can detect that it's the same person because the vendorIdentifier is the same. A user can circumvent this by deleting/reinstalling the app, but that's about the same amt of effort as making a new email address.

Comment: @JohnScalo, we do not have a native app, it is essentially just a website so I do not believe this would work in my situation. I updated my question to make this more clear.

Comment: @RyanGriffith Trying to figure out a solution for this exact scenario. What did you end up doing?

Comment: @ScorpionKing, nothing at the moment. I had to move on and shelf this for now. If you come up with some, please come back and share your experience.